# Question re: use of "the" before government?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Should one use "the" before government?

> Bringing change in government and its policies"

For a country's government's policies, should one use "the" before country name only for US and not India?

> "Studying Indian government's approach and the US government's approach"

Typically there is no article used before the noun "India" (e.g. he went to India) but it is used before "US" (e.g. "the US").

Should "the" be used before "India's government" or "india's policy?"

It seems that the answer will depend on whether the definite article is modifying the definiteness of "India" or the "government/policy." For the former, there will be no "the," unlike the latter.

Thoughts?

Comment: Depends on whether you're talking about a specific government or the general concept of government.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the above cases? It seems that "bringing change in government" relates to the general notion of government. Does the same apply to using the before public e.g. "choosing to serve public" over "choosing to serve the public?"

Comment: English is consistent in it's inconsistencies -- "public" is different from "government".   (Although actually there is some consistency -- "public" without "the" implies the individual person on the street, whereas "the public" implies the body of people as a whole.)

Comment: Does Indian government need a "the?"

Comment: Normal US usage would be to say "the Indian government" or "the government of India" when speaking of the organization headed by Pranab Mukherjee.

Comment: I am not sure if it would be the same if one used "India's government" instead of "indian government." Why if there is any difference?

Comment: You are correct that no definite article would be used with "India's government".  I can't tell you what the contravening "rule" is in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should put *the* before *governement* if you are talking about a specific government (i.e.: *the* United States *government*, *the government* of India).

Comment: Should "the" be used before "India's government" or "india's policy?"

Comment: No, in that case you would not.